# EXCEL AVERAGE values for multiple criteria

Tags: excel, average

I am trying to get an average  of values in a column but only for those rows that match multiple certain criteria, for example:

```
Name    Age Pass    Country
Bob     18  TRUE    UK
John    16  FALSE   UK
Jane    17  TRUE    US
Jake    18  TRUE    Germany
```

I'd like to get an average age for those students that have passed a test and are from US or Germany.

I've tried something like this:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B2:B5, C2:C5, "TRUE", D2:D5, "US", D2:D5, "Germany")
```

But it just returns #DIV/0! error :(

Comment: because there can't be a case where the country is "US" `AND` is also "Germany"

Comment: That's why I am looking for a way to average values that are either or but at the same time are "TRUE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With AverageIfs the conditions are used with an AND, not with an OR in the logic. To achieve what you describe, you can use this array formula, which must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=AVERAGE(IF((C2:C5)*((D2:D5="US")+(D2:D5="Germany")),B2:B5))
```

After array-entering the formula, the formula bar will show curly braces around the formula. If you edit the formula, you need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Non array method can be solved this way, although its not as elegant as array formula could do

[image]

The formulas can be combined into

```
=( SUMIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5,TRUE,D2:D5,"US")+SUMIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5,TRUE,D2:D5,"Germany") ) / ( COUNTIFS(C2:C5,TRUE,D2:D5,"US")+COUNTIFS(C2:C5,TRUE,D2:D5,"Germany") )
```